# insert data from db in array Laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

```
//controller function
public function storeBaritems()
{
    $id = Auth::user()->id;
    $bartypearray = array();
    $bartypes = request('select1');     // <select id="select1" name="select1[]"
    $r = 0;
    foreach ($bartypes as $type) {
        $bartypearray[$r] = Bartype::select('bartype_id')
                            ->where('bar_type_name','like',$type)
                            ->where('restaurant_id','like',$id)
                            ->get();
        $r += 1;
    }
    $baritems = request('itemname');   //<input type="text" class="hookah-field" name="itemname[]">
    $descriptions = request('description');  //<input type="text" class="hookah-field" name="description[]">
    $quantity = request('quantity'); //<input type="text" class="hookah-field" name="quantity[]">
    $prices = request('price');  //<input type="text" class="hookah-field" name="price[]">
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($baritems as $item) {
            Bar_menu::create([
                'item_name'=>$item,      
                'description'=>$descriptions[$i], 
                'quantity'=>$quantity[$i],
                'price'=>$prices[$i],
                'res_id'=>$id,
                'type_id'=>$bartypearray[$i]
                ]);
            $i += 1;
    }
}
```

The HTML is dynamic form and it generates new input fields with same "name" attribute. After calling the function from route, I am getting this error as in screenshot
[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iPZVJ.png)

I think problem is with inserting the data in `bartypearray[]`. Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

In your first foreach loop, when you try to populate $bartypearray with data, you are actually populating it with an object array. That's why you get a '[]' as an input instead of an integer.

What I suggest you do, is to access the bartypeid in the second foreach loop like this:
'type_id'=$bartypearray[$i] -> bartypeid;

I think it should work..

Comment: It didn't work. Getting error - "Property [bartype_id] does not exist on this collection instance."